# how to fix third party script in next js

Tags: performance, next.js

```
        <Wrapper
        target="_blank"
        href="https://www.google.com/search?q=project%20landscape&oq=project+landscape&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64j69i60l3.2120j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:14&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=AJOqlzVRUU_ZaNptPsOjzHtILa57paj9uQ:1676341266052&rflfq=1&num=10&rldimm=11747008283103314784&lqi=ChFwcm9qZWN0IGxhbmRzY2FwZUi-z42FnKuAgAhaGxAAEAEYABgBIhFwcm9qZWN0IGxhbmRzY2FwZXoHQ2FsZ2FyeZIBEmxhbmRzY2FwZV9kZXNpZ25lcg&ved=2ahUKEwjnu73t-ZP9AhVKGzQIHdw6BLIQvS56BAgWEAE&sa=X&rlst=f#rlfi=hd:;si:11747008283103314784,l,ChFwcm9qZWN0IGxhbmRzY2FwZUi-z42FnKuAgAhaGxAAEAEYABgBIhFwcm9qZWN0IGxhbmRzY2FwZXoHQ2FsZ2FyeZIBEmxhbmRzY2FwZV9kZXNpZ25lcg;mv:[[50.997355899999995,-113.98204679999999],[50.9522124,-114.01662379999999]];tbs:lrf:!1m4!1u3!2m2!3m1!1e1!1m4!1u2!2m2!2m1!1e1!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:14"
      >
        <Flex>
          <GoogleIcon style={googleStyle} />
          <div className="">
            <p className="body--small">Google Rating</p>
            <div className="header">
              <span>4.8</span>
              <FlexStars>
                {[...Array(5)].map((_, index) => (
                  <StarIcon key={index} style={fontStyle} />
                ))}
              </FlexStars>
            </div>
            <p className="body--small">Based on 90 reviews</p>
          </div>
        </Flex>
      </Wrapper>
```

this component is server side component because google map rating url getting third party code issue in performance